# How to convert image text to normal text with a tool or a script

Tags: script

I would like to know whether is there any tool or a script to recognise the text which is in .png format and get the output as a plain text.

Answer (score 0):

The technology is called [optical character recognition](https://www.google.com/#q=optical+character+recognition) or OCR. There are online tools as well as downloadable programs (both free and commercial) that you can use, depending on your operating system, the number of images you need to convert, and the complexity of the images.